# Only one background task listed although I have a PeriodicTask and a ResourceIntensiveTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my app I am creating both a PeriodicTask and a ResourceIntensiveTask, both of which have different descriptions.

Under settings, applications, background tasks I only see the description of the PeriodicTask.  Is this normal, or does it mean I've messed something up?

Thanks,
    Damian

Answer (score 2):

Each app can only have one background task, but you can check which type of task would like to be run by the system by checking the ScheduleTask object from the OnInvoke method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=VS.92).aspx.

Edit: The description is only mandatory for the periodic task which get's show as the agent description. For the resource intensive task you'll need to provide a description.

Comment: That's when they are invoked.  Even though you have a single agent you register it as both a periodic and resource intensive task... and when you register, you provide a description.  It looks like it only picks up one description.

Answer (score 2):

ResourceIntensiveTask will not show up in the settings only PeriodicTask. Under advanced will your app listed. This is my experience.